# Asp.Net MVC submit button doesn' t post values to my method in Controller while using onclick javascript function for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I am saving my data for the first time (when clicked on save button of my view) then I am getting value of `submitButton` variable in my controller action. But when I am editing my view and then click on save then I am getting `null` value in `submitButton` variable in my controller action.

My View Model

```
public class TermiViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My View

```
@model TermiViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyActionMethod", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

  <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
  </div>

  <button name="submitButton" value="Save" type="submit" 
    onclick="return JavaScriptFunction();">Save</button> 

  <button name="submitButton" value="Cancel" type="submit" 
    onclick="return JavaScriptFunction();">Cancel</button> 
}
```

Below is the Javascript I am using in my view.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function JavaScriptFunction() {
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Below is my Controller class.

```
public class MyController : CoreMvcController
{
  private readonly ITermiRepositoryService _termiRepository;
  public MyController(ITermiRepositoryService termiRepository)
  {
    _termiRepository = termiRepository;
  }
}
```

Below is my action Method where I am getting values from my view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionMethod(TermiViewModel termiViewModel, string submitButton)
{
  try
  {
    voucherViewModel =_termiRepository.Save(termiViewModel);
    switch (submitButton)
    {
      case "Cancel":
        return RedirectToAction("Edit",termiViewModel.Id);
      default:
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

In my above Controller method I get the `null` value for my `submitButton` variable while editing my view. I don't understand why I am getting `null` value because while creating for the first time, I am getting values of `submitButton` from the submit button.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Replace "MyController" to "My"...@using (Html.BeginForm("MyActionMethod", "My", FormMethod.Post)) { } and also no need of onclick()..

Comment: @Jilani Thanks for your comment.Yes, you are right that I have to replace MyController but onClick() is needed for validation purpose. But all that does not give a solution to my problem.

Comment: it's working fine for me...i tried your code...

Comment: @Jilanipasha It's working fine for me as well but as mentioned in the question, it is working only once when I am creating new one but as soon as I edit the existing one, and then click on save button, I get null value in my controller action.

Comment: can you show your edit action method and view code...

Answer (score 0):

For the solution, I need to change following classes:

My View Model:

```
// A new property "SaveButtonValue" added to my view model.

public class TermiViewModel : ViewModelBase
{    

  public long Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string SaveButtonValue { get; set; }

}
```

My View:

```
// Added a hidden field for "SaveButtonValue" and passing this keyword in
// Javascript function for onclick of submit button.

@model TermiViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyActionMethod", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))  
{

  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SaveButtonValue)

  <div>

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

  </div>


  <button name="submitButton" value="Save" type="submit" 
   onclick="return JavaScriptFunction(this);">Save</button> 

  <button name="submitButton" value="Cancel" type="submit" 
   onclick="return JavaScriptFunction(this);">Cancel</button> 
}
```

Javascript:

```
// Populating my property "SaveButtonValue" through javascript

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  function JavaScriptFunction(submitButton)
  {

      if (objButton) {
          $('#SaveButtonValue').val(submitButton.value);
      }

      return true;
  }
</script>
```

My action method:

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult MyActionMethod(TermiViewModel termiViewModel)
{

  try
  {
    voucherViewModel =_termiRepository.Save(termiViewModel);

    switch (termiViewModel.SaveButtonValue)
    {
      case "Cancel":
        return RedirectToAction("Edit",termiViewModel.Id);

      default:
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }

  }

  catch (Exception exception)
  {

  }

  return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```